# Why can't pass queue as argument in pool module?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue, pool

```
vim  mp_without_queue.py
from multiprocessing import Pool
n = 3 
def hello(i):
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)

pool = Pool(processes = 2)
for i in range(n):
    pool.apply_async(hello,args=(i,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I create two processes and add three task (call hello function 3 times).

```
python3 mp_without_queue.py
hello
hello
hello
```

It works fine.
Now i just add queue in the arguments,do nothing in called function with the `queue` passed .

```
vim  mp_with_queue.py
from multiprocessing import Pool,Queue
q = Queue()
n = 3 
def hello(i,q):
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)

pool = Pool(processes = 2)
for i in range(n):
    pool.apply_async(hello,args=(i,q))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

It get nothing when to execute .

```
python3 mp_with_queue.py
#nothing as output
```

Why can't pass queue as argument in pool module?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass queue to function itself, it gets copied and doesn't have access to original object. You need to pass it to initializer with `initargs` and setup a global variable in `initializer` within each process. In this case your process will have access to original object - Queue.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import time

queue: Queue


def init(q):
    global queue
    queue = q


def hello(i):
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)
    queue.put(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()

    n = 3

    pool = Pool(processes=2, initializer=init, initargs=(q,))
    for i in range(n):
        pool.apply_async(hello, args=(i,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get())
```

Here is output:

```
hello
hello
hello
1
0
2
```

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds The code and note above is correct and valid, I can personally confirm that. I used AI to fix my grammar mistakes and tone of the text. But I can sign under the answer that this is correct.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds changed the answer that it doesn't use corrections of AI :D

Comment: Thanks!  Personally I have no problem with AI being used for grammar corrections.  And I even support the [responsible use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) of AI more generally.  Unfortunately, we do get a lot of AI-assisted or written answers that have more serious issues :-/.

Comment: The line `queue: Queue` ,what does it mean here?The whole codes can work after deleting the `queue: Queue`.

Comment: It is no need to write `pool = Pool(processes=2, initializer=init, initargs=(q,))`,`pool = Pool(processes=2)` can work!

Comment: @showkey defining global variable so IDE knows type and don't say "defining global variable in local scope". Just good style

Comment: @showkey did you check it yourself? It doesn't work without initializer. Initial queue is empty after exiting child processes. The thing is to pass queue to child process in a correct way without copying object.

Answer (score 0):

`Queue` is designed to share in all process by default,so no need to pass it into function,it can be called directly.

```
vim mp_pool.py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import time

def hello(i):
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)
    q.put(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    n = 5
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    for i in range(n):
        pool.apply_async(hello, args=(i,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get())
```

Run it with `python3 mp_pool.py`:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
1
0
3
2
4
```

Conclusion:Pass queue's instance into funciton will cause an error,use it in all child process and parent process directly.